# How can I import asciidoc files from gitHub files into Zendesk as articles?

Tags: git, github, zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

I have a handful of asciidoc/README type files associated with some of my project repositories in gitHub. I am using Zendesk as a support portal and knowledge base. I would like to build an app that will push these doc files into Zendesk as searchable articles whenever my repo builds.

My hope is that Zendesk has an API that allows for the automated creation of articles or the importing of articles from some remote source. This is the shamefully small amount of homework I have done so far: https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/223719427-Zendesk-API-input-import-tool

...has anyone done something similar and perhaps know what resources to point me to start writing said custom script?

Comment: jpalmieri's answer is exactly what I was looking for. thx again. https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/help_center/articles PUT and POST methods are my in-roads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the API you're looking for:
https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/help_center/introduction

I've done some similar stuff with Zendesk, e.g. copied articles from Zendesk to a sandbox instance of Zendesk:

https://github.com/jpalmieri/zendesk_help_center_scripts/blob/master/scripts/hc_importer.rb

However, this was a long time ago and I'm not sure if it even works anymore. You probably only want to use this as reference.

Comment: perfect. not sure how I kept skimming right over it, but specifically, the post and put methods on the articles API is what I need. https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/help_center/articles